# (Needs Optimizing) - MySQL Select from several tables with the latest value in one table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables in my database

- Beneficiary. `PK: BeneficiaryId`
  this table lists the beneficiaries from a health insurance database.
- PolicyBeneficiary. `PK: BeneficiaryId AND PolicyId` This is the resulting table from a Many to Many relationship between the beneficiary and an insurance policy.
- Policy. `PK: PolicyId` This table lists all the policies, each with a beginning date and end date of the policy.
- TableOfBenefits. `PK: PolicyId AND BenefitId` This table is the resulting table from a Many to Many relationship between the policy and the benefit, it contains the limit, maximum number of sessions for each benefit...etc for that policy.
- BenefitId. `PK: BenefitId` This table lists the benefits along with their categories.

What I am trying to do here is get the rows from `TableOfBenefits` table for a one `Beneficiary`, based on the last policy he is listed in in the `PolicyBeneficiary` table.

I managed to come up with this joined sub-query to get the last policy for a beneficiary, then join it with the data I need, it gets the job done, but I am not sure that this is the optimized solution for my problem.

```
SELECT 
     Benefit.BenefitId
    ,Benefit.Name
    ,TableOfBenefits.BenefitLimit
    ,TableOfBenefits.Percentage
    ,TableOfBenefits.Sessions 
FROM TableOfBenefits 
INNER JOIN Benefit 
    ON TableOfBenefits.BenefitId = Benefit.BenefitId 
INNER JOIN (    
            SELECT Policy.PolicyId 
            FROM Policy 
            INNER JOIN PolicyBeneficiary 
                ON Policy.PolicyId = PolicyBeneficiary.PolicyId     
            WHERE PolicyBeneficiary.BeneficiaryId = 2
            ORDER BY PolicyId DESC LIMIT 1 
            ) Policy 
    ON TableOfBenefits.PolicyId = Policy.PolicyId
```

I am trying to find out whether this is the best solution for my problem or if there is another more optimized solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added small modification removed where clause and it added to the join operation in that case initially it will filter that result and then join it with other table

```
SELECT 
     Benefit.BenefitId
    ,Benefit.Name
    ,TableOfBenefits.BenefitLimit
    ,TableOfBenefits.Percentage
    ,TableOfBenefits.Sessions 
FROM TableOfBenefits 
INNER JOIN Benefit 
    ON TableOfBenefits.BenefitId = Benefit.BenefitId 
INNER JOIN (    
            SELECT Policy.PolicyId 
            FROM Policy 
            INNER JOIN PolicyBeneficiary 
                ON Policy.PolicyId = PolicyBeneficiary.PolicyId     
            AND PolicyBeneficiary.BeneficiaryId = 2
            ORDER BY PolicyId DESC LIMIT 1 
            ) Policy 
    ON TableOfBenefits.PolicyId = Policy.PolicyId
```

Comment: Indeed, better to filter within the join instead of putting it in the where clause.